# "SplFileInfo::getSize(): stat failed" exception on Laravel 6.0 when doing file upload

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, file-upload, xampp

I'm using Laravel 6.0 to build a simple image upload system.

But for some odd reason, I keep encountering a "SplFileInfo::getSize(): stat failed" exception even though the image is successfully uploaded to the correct folder... is there something I can do to either 1) skip this exception and hide it 2) fix it entirely?

I did see a solution to change max_file_size and post_max_size etc etc to a higher value and restart Apache. I tried that but it didn't work either... and it looks like there aren't any clear cut solutions for this.

Here is what I have on my controller for the upload function

```
public function fileUpload(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'img' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,',
        ]);

        if ($request->hasFile('img')) {
            $image = $request->file('img');
            $size = $image->getSize();
            $characters = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
            $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
            $randomString = '';
            for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
                $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)]; // Generate random 5 character name...
            }
            $name = $randomString.'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $destinationPath = public_path('storage'.'\\'.$request->input('post'));

            // Store Image Information //
            $data = new Photo();
            // Get post number //
            $data->order = $request->input('post');
            $data->filename = $name;
            $data->location = $destinationPath;
            $data->save();

            // Now move to the destination path //
            $image->move($destinationPath, $name);

            return refresh();
        }
    }
```

I'm using MySQL to store photo information such as which post the image is associated with, the file name generated by the controller, and where in the machine the image is being stored... as you can see, I am creating separate folders for each post for organization purposes...

The goal is to at least disable the exception cause otherwise the whole thing works fine... I should theoretically just refresh the page once the upload is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Guys, I figured it out...**

There might need to be a minor update in Laravel to address this issue... because it's an odd "bug".

SO, apparently, you MUST do a `getSize();`, in my case `$size = $image->getSize();` and store that value somewhere whether it be on a SQL database... even if you don't need the data... simply storing it as a variable will throw the error.

Once I did `return $size`, the error disappeared and returned the bytes value of the image size... When I stored it as a mySQL value in a column, the issue wasn't present again...

I hope this helps someone. lol. If you encounter this issue and you don't understand, I'll be happy to explain. :)

Comment: hi, why we even need that getSize(); we dont need the size.

Comment: You can’t do a file upload without doing it. I’ve tried.

Comment: i was looking for the answer, and o found that if you increase the `upload_max_size` in `php.ini` file. this error will be resolved, and it work.

Answer (score 0):

U can get size with File class

```
$size = File::size($pathFile);
```

Comment: `SplFileInfo::getSize(): stat failed for C:\xampp\tmp\phpC266.tmp` I still get this error. Even though `getSize()` is no longer in the code...

Comment: Try with native php code .$spl=new SplFileInfo($_FILES['img']['name']); echo $spl->getSize();

Comment: Maybe require permission if haven't permission maybe give error .

Comment: `SplFileInfo::getSize(): stat failed for C:\xampp\tmp\php8009.tmp` Still the same error. I wonder if there is a way to turn off this exception...

Comment: did you try to increase the upload_max_size in php.ini file?

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation first the way you are saving an image was stopped in laravel 5.4 use latest version as documented by laravel

```
$path = $request->photo->store('images');
$path = $request->photo->storeAs('images', 'filename.jpg');
```

where `images` is the desitination path and `filename.jpg` is the name if incase u dont want autogenerated unique id with a path

Hope it helps

Comment: But its nolonger in documentation from laravel 5.5+ check link https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/requests#storing-uploaded-files

Answer (score 0):

Also take in mind, if you are using ancient methods to manipulate with file e.g.:

```
 $request->pdf_file->move(storage_path(self::DIRECTORY), $fileName);
```

You should move towards using more modern:

```
 $file = $request->file('pdf_file');
```

Because this deprecated method will cause error itself. (update from 5.5 to 6.0)

Answer (score 0):

By reading documentation of laravel 6.* you can see for uploading file you can use `store` method.
if you want to storing file in public or public_html at first run `php artisan vendor:publish` and in `config->filesystems.php` define new disks for example with name of `public_local` and set the root of this disk to public address:

```
'public_local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path(),
        ],
```

then in order to store file in this disk you can use store method that set a unique name for your file or use storeas with custom name:
with store method:

```
$path = $request->file('image_url')->store($imagePath, 'public_local');
```

```
$path = $request->file('image_url')->storeAs($imagePath, 'custom_name', 'public_local');
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error "SplFileInfo::getSize(): stat failed for C:\xampp\tmp\phpE84D.tmp"

How i resolved it -

Because i was saving the original file name in DB but my db column had the size varchar 30 and the file which i had uploading thats file name was too long. So when i rename the file with shorter name. That got uploaded. So then i had increased my column size and what i got, This error had gone.

So if anybody using the function $image->getClientOriginalName() in your file upload code and saving it to the DB, you have to validate for file name or have to increase the db column size.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't get it to work so I uses the old approach from Laravel 5.5, and it still works:

```
   $filenameWithExt = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
   $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
   $extension = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
   $fileNameToStore = $filename . '_' . time() . '.' . $extension;
   $path = $request->file('image')->storeAs('public/profile_images', 
   $fileNameToStore);
   $user->profile_image = $fileNameToStore;
   $user->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem occurred. As a solution, I just added the nullable function to the table.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('logos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('favicon')->nullable();
        $table->string('homepage_logo')->nullable();
        $table->string('otherpage_logo')->nullable();
        $table->string('preloader')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

LogoController.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    if($request->has('favicon') || $request->has('homepage_logo') || $request->has('otherpage_logo') || $request->has('preloader')){

        $favicon = $request->file('favicon');

        $favicon_name =  time().'.'.$favicon->getClientOriginalName();

        $folder = 'empathy/adminpanel/assets/img/icon/';

        $favicon->move($folder, $favicon_name);

        $input['favicon']= $favicon_name;
    }
    Logo::create($input);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  `extension()` method instead of `getClientOriginalName()`